# Updating SWT UI components in child composite gives null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, swt, abstract-class

I have an `AbstractViewPart` class extending `ViewPart` defined with `createHeaderComposite()` abstract methods. However when I try to update the label on the child composite, it throws a null pointer exception.

Any idea what could be the issue?

```
    public abstract class AbstractViewPart extends ViewPart
    {
       protected AbstractComposite m_headerComposite = null;

       public abstract AbstractComposite createHeaderComposite(Composite parent);

       @Override
       public void createPartControl(Composite parent)
       {
          m_headerComposite = createHeaderComposite(parent);
       }

      private class IC_SelectionListener implements ISelectionListener 
      {
         public void selectionChanged(final IWorkbenchPart part, final ISelection selection) {
            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (selection != null) {
                        if (selection instanceof StructuredSelection) {
                            StructuredSelection ss = (StructuredSelection) selection;
                            if (!ss.isEmpty())
                            {
                                    if( ss.getFirstElement() instanceof AIFComponentContext)
                                    {
                                        m_selectedComp = ((AIFComponentContext) (ss.getFirstElement())).getComponent();
                                        m_headerComposite.updateComposite();
                                    }                                       
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

public class MyView extends AbstractViewPart 
{

    @Override
    public AbstractComposite createHeaderComposite(Composite parent) 
    {
        return new MyHeaderComposite(parent, getSelectedObject());      
    }       
}

public abstract class AbstractComposite extends Composite
{
    protected InterfaceAIFComponent m_selectedComp = null;

    public abstract void createComposite();
    public abstract void updateComposite();

    public AbstractComposite(Composite parent, int style) 
    {
        super(parent, style);
        createComposite();
    }

    public AbstractComposite(Composite parent, int style, InterfaceAIFComponent comp) 
    {
        super(parent, style);
        this.m_selectedComp = comp;
        createComposite();
    }

    public InterfaceAIFComponent getSelectedComponent()
    {
        return m_selectedComp;
    }
}

public class MyHeaderComposite extends AbstractComposite
{   
    private Label m_lblObjectName   = null;

    public MyHeaderComposite(Composite parent, InterfaceAIFComponent comp) 
    {
        super(parent, SWT.NONE, comp);      
    }

    @Override
    public void createComposite() 
    {
        //This is the Header Composite to which we add other composites and elements
        //Apply layout to this Header Composite
        GridData gd_composite = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false);
        this.setLayoutData(gd_composite);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

        //Start adding other elements to this Header composite      
        m_lblObjectName = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        m_lblObjectName.setFont(new Font(Display.getDefault(), "Segoe UI", 15, SWT.NORMAL));
        m_lblObjectName.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
        m_lblObjectName.setText(m_selectedComp.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateComposite() 
    {       
        this.m_lblObjectName.setText(m_selectedComp.toString()); // m_lblObjectName is always null. Throws null pointer exception   
    }
}
```

In the updateComposite() method, in debug mode, I can see the value of 'this' which is MyHeaderComposite{} but the ui labels in it are null.

Here is the stack trace:

```
ERROR: 14:56:10,922  - TcLogger$IC_LogListener.logging:?
org.eclipse.core.runtime - org.eclipse.ui - 0 - Unhandled event loop exception
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.teamcenter.rac.aifrcp.Application.runApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.rac.aifrcp.Application.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hm.teamcenter.rac.views.MyHeaderComposite.updateComposite(MyHeaderComposite.java:47)
    at com.hm.teamcenter.rac.views.AbstractViewPart.updateHeaderComposite(AbstractViewPart.java:174)
    at com.hm.teamcenter.rac.views.AbstractViewPart.updateSelectionChange(AbstractViewPart.java:161)
    at com.hm.teamcenter.rac.views.AbstractViewPart$IC_SelectionListener$1.run(AbstractViewPart.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace

Comment: Added the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Calling `new MyHeaderComposite(parent)` doesn't hit any of the custom constructors you defined and consequently won't call `createComposite()`.

Consequently, `this.m_lblObjectName` in `updateComposite()` is `null` as it hasn't been set yet.

Comment: Added getSelectedObject() parameter in "new MyHeaderComposite(parent)" code line and still same error appears

Comment: @user1039499 Can you check that what `getSelectedObject()` returns isn't `null`?

Comment: Its not null. It has valid component. I am guessing something to do with the scope of the UI controls defined on the child instead of the parent composite.

Comment: @user1039499 Can you set a breakpoint in both `createComposite()` and `updateComposite()` and see which one gets called first?

Comment: First createComposite() is called. further, inside, updateComposite(), value of 'this' shows MyHeaderComposite{}

Comment: @user1039499 Well, I ran out of ideas... Good luck though.